# Display all Unicode chars in TextView

Tags: android, unicode, textview

Is there any way to show all Unicode chars in my TextView, on my phone?

I have tried special characters like '\u0279' and I get something like box (default char).
Is this based on l10n and i18n settings?

Comment: Are you adding these characters in Strings.xml file?

Comment: Let's say that I want to do simple transformation from (utf8) number (e.g. 0279) to (utf8) char '\u0279'. So I have EditText into which user writes down number and TextView in which this numbers are converted to chars. By pressing a button transformation is done.

Comment: For doing this, you must have a record of all the available char code for the respective symbols. Compare it with the records and then show the symbol.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you ment by having record? Can you post a sample code in answer pls?

Comment: Sorry for record thing that was a mix up. Check my answer.

Comment: A square usually means that no font is available that can render the desired glyph (or the select font can't display it and no fallback is used). It's **very** rare to find a system that can display **all** Unicode characters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "TAU_BHON.TTF");
tv.setTypeface(font);
```

Place the font that will support your language in the assets folder.In this case i have used TAU_BHON.TTF

Comment: I'm getting error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: I have successfully loaded font from asset and still I'm getting this ugly box instead of proper char.

Comment: How did you determine which font you needed?

Comment: @McAdam331 Each font supports different unicode characters, no font supports all of them.  You need to select one that supports the characters you want to use.

Comment: @TristanWiley my question is, how do I determine the font(s) that support the characters I want to use?

Comment: You could just check fonts and see if they work.  Many fonts support a lot of characters so I would try with those.

Answer (score 13):

This usually happens because of the **font** used, the default one **does not support/have implemented all unicode chars**, you need to use a full featured font like DejaVuSans.ttf

@sakthi shows a sample that should work without problem, check if your android version supports it

Comment: As I mentioned I'm getting error java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mypackage/mypackage.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: rigth, but that sample says : Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "TAU_BHON.TTF");  try instead of only getAssests() something like getContext().getAssests(), maybe is because of can not get the context

Comment: I have successfully loaded font from asset and still I'm getting this ugly box instead of proper char.

Comment: check if the font you are using has your chars, those what you need

Comment: OK now I'm using DejaVuSans.ttf and now works almost perfectly (not all chars are shown as wanted, but is OK). Thx

Comment: but the problem is Dejavu fonts are large (>230KB).

Comment: @yeradis，thanks for your font(DejaVuSans.ttf), i struggled the same issue for whole, changed a lot of fonts and almost gave up. Thanks so much. By the way and just be curious, any better font choice than DejaVuSans.ttf?

Answer (score 11):

Try this code:

```
String str = "\u00F6";

System.out.println("new value-" + str);
```

You will get:

```
new value-ö
```

**Here is a sample android project that i created to check the feature:**

Java file:

```
package com.testd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String str = "\u00F6";

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a);
        tv.setText("sajklasdklfjasdf " + str );
    }
}
```

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/a" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen Shot:

[image]

Comment: That is all true, but problem is that my TextView does not show it that way. It uses boxes instead of propert chars

Comment: The line `String s = new String(str);` does absolutely nothing productive. It simply creates a new `String` with the **same content** as `s`. There are very, very few cases where the `String` constructor that takes only a single `String` is useful. This is not one of them.

Comment: This code works for me too, but if you use "\u2040" instead of "\u00F6" it does not work any more.