# How to display korean text on Textview?

Tags: android, localization, cjk

I want to display Korean text in my TextView. It should display proper Korean language but instead it's displaying junk chars. Any one know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Android use a Unicode font, so it can display Korean character normally.
You can try change your text encoding of your project because its not android problem.

Comment: I agree. I suggest you ensure the file you're loading from is set to utf8 encoding. I have loaded chinese and korean from xml and csv files without any problem.

Comment: I am getting the response string as           StreamTitle=ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ 5ï¿½ï¿½ - 10 ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ ï¿½ï¿½ (ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½).mp3  this streamtitle is the song name coming with korean language I want to set this text to my songtitle textview but if ll set the text to textview its showing the same string , what i want that it should display the song name in proper korean language.

Comment: Seem that string isnt in Unicode format. In this case you should follow xjaphx answer.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to load a korean font to the TextView, like Batang, BatangChe, Dotum.. 
This is similar question to yours: [Display all Unicode chars in TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview)

Answer (score 0):

You require a True Type font(ttf) file to support the language it seems. copy and paste the korean font file into your assets folder and try this code.

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/yourfontname.ttf");
    holder.text.setTypeface(font);
    holder.text.setText(your_variable);
```