# Textview properly displaying encoded text

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding

I have an app that read load up a text file and display the text.  Now, the text file could be in English, Chinese, or whatever language.  My question is, how do I properly display the characters without showing gibberish.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

refer to this link.

[How to display korean text on Textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632568/how-to-display-korean-text-on-textview)

You require a True Type font(ttf) file to support the language you wish. Include the respective font file into your assets folder and try this code.

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "your-choice-font.ttf");
holder.text.setTypeface(font);
holder.text.setText(content_read_from_TxtFile);
```