# how to insert proportion symbol in my textview

Tags: android, fonts

trying to insert proportion symbol in my textview using its unicode is not working, as if it is not supported by android default font roboto, so how can achive it, using any ttf file
Thanx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display all Unicode chars in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview).

> Place the font that will support your language in the assets folder. In
>   this case I have used TAU_BHON.TTF
>
> ```
> tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
> Typeface font= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "TAU_BHON.TTF");
> tv.setTypeface(font);
> ```

Comment: This answer should be a comment, instead.

Comment: As i dont have 50 rep i couldn't so i thought it should be an answer becasue this will help him.

Comment: @MatthewGalbraith Yes, however, if the question has been answered by an answer from another question, then the question is a duplicate.