# Cube root symbol not show in textview using unicode '\u221B'

Tags: android, unicode

I want to display cube root sign in android textview using Unicode \u221B.
it not show on textview but show in log cart.

```
TextView txtcube_sqrt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtcube_sqrt);
txtcube_sqrt.setText("\u221B");
```

If i am using Unicode '\u221A' for Square root it work properly.

please somebody help me for solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens due to the font being used may not have a vast support for unicode characters. Use a font which has support for the desired unicode characters and you should be good to go. For more info, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview).

Answer (score 0):

Just set this symbol like this:

```
yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf('\u221B'));
```

or

```
 yourTextView.setText(Character.toString('\u221B'));
```

Comment: i have try given your both solution but still have same problem.

Comment: cube root symbol show in log cart on print text but also not show in Toast