# Wrong Charset in Shared Preferences

Tags: android, preferences, shared

I have a problem with Shared Preferences. I want to store some Stings and they could contain special characters like "äöü".
Shared Preferences should be able to show and save those characters since its in UTF - 8 right?
Somehow it doesn't, it shows only this questionmark Symbol. Is there an option I missed to set the right charset?

Comment: SharedPreferences are indeed stored in UTF-8. What is your exact code? Where does the äöü come from?

Comment: I used this code just to test it  editor.putString("test", "ä @?ß"); and I read it with Log.e("prefstest",prefs.getString("test",null)); and the result is:"E/prefstest﹕ � @?�"

Comment: Your log viewer or the log itself may be the problem, if it doesn't render. Are you sure !prefs.getString("test", "").equals("ä @?ß")?

Comment: It is equal! So my problem is only where I display it, Thanks! I had the problem on a bigger scale thats why I tested it. Need to test further what could cause my app to crash with those characters.

Answer (score 0):

i think SharedPreferences stores it right but problem is in where you are displaying this characters.

You need to take care while displaying these chars

Comment: Yes thats it. Its not a problem with the storing, the problem is where it is displayed

Comment: you can refer this answer ,       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview  this solves problem by using fonts