# my App showing question marks instead of arabic words when retrieve data for sql server?

Tags: android

i have an android taxi booking app and there is interface between this app and sql server to store data coming from it . the problem is : when i am trying to store any Arabic data to sql server the app retrieve  this data as question marks ??????? instead of arabic words . i do not know this issue from server side or from android source code (java) . i already change the encoding in server side to utf-8 genereal_ci  but still i am facing the same issue . your help will be highly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Maybe duplicate question with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682175/android-issue-with-encoding-arabic-words) ?

Answer (score 1):

The N prefix only works on the actual string not a copy of it so:

```
declare @name nvarchar(50);
set @name = N'محسن';
insert into tests values(@name)
```

Comment: i have change the collation and character set  in sql database to utf-8_general_ci but no effect . the App still showing ?????? .