# Reading a file in Gujarati language using java but getting "?"

Tags: java, file, unicode

I'm reading a file which is in unicode using java.

Here is my file:[image]

its encoding says unicode.
[image]

but whenever I try to read this using UTF-8 or UTF-16 in java it reads english words correctly but can not read other words which are in gujarati language. It gives ????? only. I had the same problem which I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061310/reading-non-english-from-ms-sql-using-jtds-1-3-0-driver-from-java). but no one answered, so changed my approach. I read the data from the MS SQL database having column nvarchar(for Gujarati language) and stored it in a file, and now trying to read the data from the file using java. But still not getting it.

I tried changing encoding of my file to UTF-8 and unicode big endian and I've tried all the [unicode formats supported in java8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html) but not getting the desired result.

this is my code of java:

```
File fileDir = new File("C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python35\\data.txt");

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileDir),"UTF-16"));

String str;

while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

in.close();
```

I directed this data to my android application through a socket connection. I'm trying to show it on textview but it is also giving me a "???" signs..
And I've tried showing gujarati language on textview directly with `textview.setText("તારુ નામ શુ છે ?")` and it shows correctly !!!..

When I try to send a hard coded string from java through a socket connection (String is same as written above) it raises this error:

> fileread.java:23: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
>                   ds.writeBytes("α¬ñα¬╛α¬░α½? α¬¿α¬╛α¬« α¬╢α½? α¬¢α½ç ?");

Comment: How do you check it? Maybe output format (console, logs) doesn't support  non-unicode characters.

Comment: I'm using cmd..@defaultlocale

Comment: Windows command line might need configuration to support unicode output. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how

Comment: You really need to isolate your problem. Jon Skeet [already told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061310/reading-non-english-from-ms-sql-using-jtds-1-3-0-driver-from-java) how to check the characters. Now you might want to check your console and your socket connection. What happens when you send a hardcoded string there?

Comment: I've updated question.@defaultlocale

Comment: Have you tried to google this error message? I suggest you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your particular problem with console output and remove irrelevant information from your question (files, sockets, android UI, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using System.out.println. That uses platform encoding and it won't have the support.

Try using PrintStream and it should work. You can configure PrintStream with:

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
```

(I also think UTF-8 should do for you).

Comment: Ok. I'll try that but my main aim is to print this data in android app's textview.

Comment: Can you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054826/display-all-unicode-chars-in-textview 
This could also be a problem with the font that you are using.

Comment: Your answer gave me another idea and i've solved my problem. Thank you so much. @Aditya K